# var available outside each loop returning empty in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-gmap3

I have a rather large script to generate my map using the gmap3 plugin. In the plugin, normally you would apply multiple map markers like follows. I know this works when applied with static data.

```
marker:{
    values:[
        {address:"555 Anywhere Rd Port Clinton, OH", data:'<h4>Some Data 1</h4>'},
        {address:"556 Anywhere Rd Port Clinton, OH", data:'<h4>Some Data 2</h4>'},
        {address:"557 Anywhere Rd Port Clinton, OH", data:'<h4>Some Data 3</h4>'} 
    ]
}
```

The problem starts when I try to pass the array `markerValues` outside an each loop and it's returning empty.

here is my full code:

```
/****************************************
*** DEALER LOCATOR MAP
****************************************/
(function($){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var tableRows = [];
        var headersText = [];
        var $headers = $("th");
        var markerValues = {};
        var $rows = $("#table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
          $cells = $(this).find("td");
          tableRows[index] = {};
          $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
            if(headersText[cellIndex] === undefined) {
              headersText[cellIndex] = $($headers[cellIndex]).text();
            }
            tableRows[index][headersText[cellIndex]] = $(this).text();
          });    
        });
        var tableData = {
            "tableData": tableRows
        };
        $(function(){
           $.each(tableData["tableData"], function(key, value){
                markerValues = {
                   address: value.STREET+" "+value.CITY+","+value.STATE+" "+value.ZIP,
                   data: '<p>'+value.NAME+'<br />'+value.STREET+'<br />'+value.CITY+', '+value.STATE+'<br /> '+value.ZIP+'<br />'+value.TEL+'</p>' 
                };
            }); 
        });      

        console.log( markerValues );

        $(function(){ 
            $('#map_canvas').gmap3({ 
              map:{
                options:{
                  zoom: 3,
                  center: [41.374774, -83.651323], 
                  streetViewControl: true,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                  mapTypeControl: true,
                  mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                  }
                }
              },
              marker:{
                values:[markerValues],
                options:{
                  draggable: false,
                  /*icon: "/static/images/mapmarker.png"*/
                },
                events:{
                  click: function(marker, event, context){
                      $(this).gmap3({
                        clear:"overlay"
                      });
                      $(this).gmap3({
                        overlay:{
                            latLng: marker.getPosition(),
                            options:{
                              content: '<div id="small_infowindow"><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12">'+(context.data)+'</div></div></div>',
                              offset:{
                                y: -30,
                                x: 30
                              }
                            }
                        }
                      });
                      $(this).gmap3('get').panTo(marker.getPosition());
                  },
                  dblclick: function() {
                    $(this).gmap3({
                        clear:"overlay"
                    });
                  }
                },
              }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable is not accesible outside of the loop

```
$.each(tableData["tableData"], function(key, value){
    var markerValues = {
        address: value.STREET+" "+value.CITY+","
          +value.STATE+" "+value.ZIP,
        data: '<p>'+value.NAME+'<br />'+value.STREET+'<br />'
          +value.CITY+', '+value.STATE+'<br /> '+value.ZIP+'<br />'
          +value.TEL+'</p>' 
    };
    console.log( markerValues );
});
```

You should define it (using the "var") outside of the loop, just before the 9th line

Comment: so var markerValues = {}; just before my each function?

Comment: yes, at the same level as rows , tableRows, headersText... why are you spamming these "$(function(){" ?

Comment: ok i added that at line 9 and moved my console log outside of the loop to see if the vales of the loop are passed, now markerValues is empty.

Comment: 1/ Fixed, i just had a syntax error 2/ Removed var in the each loop, still returning empty.

Comment: updated the question, thanks. still not solved though.

Comment: ok it is working now, the problem is now i am only getting one result in the marker values on the map. grrr if not one  thing, another.

Comment: the fact is that using the "=" symbol you do an affectation at each iteration of the loop. This means you erase the content of the variable at each iteration. You probably want to store it in an array (using the function push)...
I do not know what you really want.

Comment: The first part of my script takes an html table an converts it to an array, then the second part (the part we are working on here) needs to take the values from the dataTable array and and create an array of address and data to be used in gmap plugin which is the third part of the script. there are somewhere in the area of 460 table rows so i should have that many in the makerValues array too.

Comment: I wonder about the   marker:{    values:[markerValues],      this can get only the last value (object) of markerValues. Maybe you should call the whole thing differently... like this : http://pastebin.com/jdVk7d3H